# Preloading a page using greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey, preloader

I've seen a few preloading questions but most of them are from people that own a website and want to implement some preloading for the user.  What I want to do is implement some preloading on some sites using greasemonkey for my own usage.

There are a few sites I frequent that have "pages" like a book.  And there are a lot of pages (with 1 MB+ images on each page in most cases) so I want to make a greasemonkey script to load the next 1-2 pages.  The URL of the next pages are predictable (they're numbered sequentially with a prefix before the number).

How should I go about doing this? Is there a way to download a webpage (including all images) and let Firefox know it has been cached?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load a page in a hidden iFrame.  It will then be cached (based on the server and your Firefox settings).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Preload page(s)
// @namespace   _pc
// @include     http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

if (window.top != window.self)  //-- Don't run on frames or iframes.
    return;

var preloadPage = "http://cheezburger.com/6555102208";

/*--- Load page in hidden iFrame.
    It will then be cached per FF and server settings.
*/
$("body").append (
    '<iframe class="GM_hiddenIFrame" src="' + preloadPage + '"></iframe>'
);

GM_addStyle ( (<><![CDATA[
    iframe.GM_hiddenIFrame {
        display:        none;
    }
]]></>).toString () );
```

Note that the `window.top != window.self` bit is added, because otherwise the script might fire on the hidden iframes, causing a recursion (possibly infinite).

---

I verified this works by:

1. Clearing Firefox's cache
2. Running this script on a test page.
3. Loading [cheezburger.com/6555102208](http://cheezburger.com/6555102208) in a different tab...
   Almost everything in Firebug's *Net* panel -- including the images -- had a status of `304 Not Modified` -- which means it was cached.

   (A fresh, cache-less, load returns status `200 OK`.)

Comment: Does Greasemonkey apply to each page "downloaded" even if it's not viewed? I just modified your code a bit to parse the URL and increment the number (i.e. `http://somepage.com/read/1`, `http://somepage.com/read/2`, etc.) and using your code, I see in Firebug that it GET 1, GET 2, GET 3, GET 4, etc. at least 8+ pages (even non existent pages like last page is 20 but it GET 28).  Without it, it only gets the current page.

Comment: The question is not clear.  Do you mean "Does Greasemonkey fire on the hidden iframes?"  If so, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12118558/331508) (and similar). ... If not, please clarify.  Edit your question if necessary and/or to use formatting.

Comment: Well I mean a greasemonkey script is only loaded once per page right? If you refresh it, it will load again and whatever the script was doing will be done again.  Using your example `http://cheezburger.com/6555102208` I basically just added some code to increment the page number so the next page is `6555102209`, `6555102210`, `6555102211`, etc.  Using your code exactly as is except changing the URL and adding the counter increment, it is getting (GET requests) up to the next 10 pages.  So I guess the GM script is being run once per page I "preload" even if I'm not viewing it.

Comment: But yea I guess I meant `Does Greasemonkey fire on the hidden iframes?`.  The GM script just runs recursively for each iframe (don't know why it only does up to 10 though).  I actually don't have much of a problem with that (preloading up to 10 pages), though I wonder if there's a way I can limit how many pages it preloads.

Comment: Preload pages by adding iframes explicitly. Don't rely on the recursion for this!  The 10 pages is either a safety limit in Firefox, or just what was reached before memory corruption. It would be a good idea to restart Firefox now. ... I modified the script to not fire on iframes, you'll usually not want that behavior for this.

Comment: Just wondering, what exactly is `window.top != window.self` doing to prevent the script from running on hidden iframes?

Comment: That's a different, additional question. In the main page `window.self === window.top`. In iframes it does not.  The script runs on the main page, and **then it runs again for every matching iframe**. Only on the iframe runs, `window.top != window.self` is true and the `return` statement stops that script instance from running further.  [Search here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greasemonkey+iframe) or ask a new question for more on that.